# Simple way to connect SMB network share?

Tags: c++, client, smb

I would like to create an .exe app which allows me to connect 
to my network share **\\localcloud\public** and then do a few things (update, copy files etc).

I know in Java there're few libraries like jCIFS, but I can't find equivalent in C++ language. I'm not interested to "mount network drive", just connect, do something with files and disconnect. Is it possible?

Comment: From what client OS?

Comment: From Windows client OS

Comment: Just use Win32API file/directory calls they know about SMB shares.

Comment: It's so simple? Wow. And what to do if authorization is needed?

Comment: See `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter in here (and also some of the flags):   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx  See also the table with the __Technology__ column in the __Remarks__ section.